# loops in Transformer Stage

Tags: datastage

I want the output of dates from particular range in a specific format

date1: 2019-06-18
date2: 2019-06-22

Output will be:

```
2019-06-19|2019-06-19,2019-06-20|2019-06-20,2019-06-21|2019-06-21
```

I want to do this via Datastage Component only, no unix, no perl script.

Comment: More information provided is always good if you expect good answers as well. So explain if this date rage will be provided in a single row and you expect how many rows (one wil multiple columns or one with one column and the contect shown or multiple)? Why is 2019-06-19 stand alone when date1 is 2019-06-18 etc.

Comment: Date 1 will be fetched from the table. Once we get the dates, I need to use this date in processing stage and  will compare it with date2 i.e  current system date. After comparision ,I need the o/p as above.for first and last dates, i can get easily in 2 different columns but for the middle dates, i am having trouble to  get the o/p in that format 2019-06-19,2019-06-20|2019-06-20,2019-06-21( on different column) .later i will combine the middle date to one column and final output will be a single row with 3 column i.e          
startt date+1| middle date| system date-1|

Answer (score 0):

From one input record you can generate multiple rows witha transformer loop.
Date1 is frim the inout and date2 could be built with currentdate() in the transformer.
In the loop @IERATION is the the loop counter so you could use [DateOffsetByDays](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Date_and_Time_Functions.html) 
with your input date and @ITERATION as second parameter. Run the loop while it is <= currentDate()

In a second transformer you could then concat whatever date format you need - ot could be helpful to add a artificial numer to all rows produced from one input row.