# Print date from particular range

Tags: datastage

I want the output of dates from particular range in a specific format

date1: 2019-06-18(from Table)
date2: 2019-06-22(systemDate)

Output will be:

2019-06-19,2019-06-20|2019-06-20,2019-06-21

Date 1 will be fetched from the table. 
Once we get the dates, I need to use this date in processing stage and will compare it with date2 i.e current system date. 
After comparision ,I need the o/p as above.
I am having trouble to get the o/p in that format 2019-06-19,2019-06-20|2019-06-20,2019-06-21( in same column if possible, otherwise I will combine the column to one).

i was trying to Use while loop in Transformer stage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loops in Transformer Stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700713/loops-in-transformer-stage)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clearly frame the question with proper i/p and expected o/p.

I guess, here you are trying to write all the result dataset into a single line, Right ?
What is your o/p  a file or a dataset ?